# How to add .bgl to GoldenDICT

Tags: permissions, goldendict

I am trying to add a glossary to my goldendict. First I opened the .bgl's containing file which in this case was a .exe one and extracted the files.
Then I used chmod to change their permissions to 777. And now that I press F3 to go to the stage of adding the glossary, the file is shown as inactive and I can not even click on it. 
what can be the problem? Could you help me fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow along sequentially:

- Open **GoldenDict**.
- Hit **F3** to open the **Dictionaries** window.
- Under **Sources -> Files** tab hit the **Add...** button from the right navigation pan. It will open a window named **Choose a directory**.
- Go on browsing until you click on the folder containing the dictionary file(s) like `.bgl`, `.dict` etc.
- Now hit **Open** button from the bottom part of the current window. This will take you back to the **Dictionaries** window that was previously opened by hitting **F3**. Now, you can see the path of the folder you had just browsed to, in the box left to the right navigation pan.
- Now hit **Rescan now** button from the right navigation pan. Wait until the scanning is complete.
- Now hit **Apply**, then **OK**.

We are nicely done. Cheers...

Comment: What you said has saved me from a lot of pain and strife! Thank you very much for your help and concern.

Comment: Right, choose a directory, not a file!! I was looking for .bgl files but they were all "greyed-out" because it needs a dir, not a file. Thanx!